# Android Room migration with Dagger 2

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, dagger

I'm using Android Room 2.3.0 and Dagger 2.

`DBModule.kt` that provides database instance looks like this:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
open fun provideDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
    return Room.databaseBuilder<AppDatabase>(
        context.applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java,
        DATABASE_NAME
    ).fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build()
}
```

`AppDatabase.kt` class:

```
@Database(
    entities = [User::class],
    version = 1,
    exportSchema = false
)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
}
```

Now I need to add a few new columns into User entity and increase db version. How can I do a migration in `AppDatabase.kt` and call `.addMigrations()` if I don't have access to Room.databaseBuilder from `AppDatabase.kt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the migrations to the `DBModule.kt` class, before calling `.build()`.

Be careful with `.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` though.

Comment: Thanks @Guido. I was thinking about same idea - keep migrations in DBModule.kt class. I'm not sure how far this idea is good, but there no other options. Unless to move DB initialization out from DBModule.kt to AppDatabase.kt.